# Develop the .net core application license issue

Tags: asp.net-core

recently I have switch to .net core. I have checked the .NET is now open source and .NET core can be developed by visual studio or visual studio code.

Below are my questions:

1. if .NET is now open source. why do I need to spend $ on the VS paid version (professional or enterprise instead of community)?
2. if I develop .NET core on VS code. How can I compile the .net core for debugging? Or i can only debug in the visual studio?

Can I develop/customize a product by only using vs community + vs code for my users commercially? (for example I want to customize an headless CMS which has the .NET core reference)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question 1. Could you please elaborate? You don't need to spend money on Visual Studio, if you don't need the premium features. And you don't need the premium features just to develop commercial .NET Core applications. Visual Studio doesn't really have anything to do with .NET being open source. .NET has been open source for more than 10 years, so it's not something that just happened "now". They started the process almost 15 years ago.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I really need to confirm with ".NET" term equals to my understand. In my country, when we develop .NET application (using C#.NET on visual studio) commercially. my company need to subscribe MSDN (and it is pretty expensive). So based on your explanation, actually we don't need to spend money at all? even my company size is 100-200 developers? Thanks

Comment: That question is a bit outside the scope of StackOverflow to be honest, but you can read the Visual Studio Community license terms. With a company of that size, you may be considered an "enterprise" and thus cannot use the community edition to develop commercial software.

Comment: Based on your explanation. .NET is open source but its IDE isn't free. while vs code is free. If I can develop .net core application on VS code. Then I should no need to pay for any subscription even through the company size is big. So the question is: .NET core can be developed in VS code. How they knew if I am using VS code or VS community or other version of VS.

Comment: They don't know. They trust that companies are professional enough to not break the terms of the license agreement of Visual Studio Community.  You could take the chance, but might find yourself in legal difficulties if an employee blows the whistle on you. You could use VS Code. Or you could pay the price of a commercial license. I'm assuming you expect to be paid for the applications your company creates as well, correct?

Answer (score 0):

> **Visual Studio Community**
>
> Visual Studio Community is an extensible free IDE, completely loaded,
> designed to build mobile software for Android, iOS, Windows, web, and
> cloud applications.
>
> Visual Studio Community is the best option if you want to use Visual
> Studio without spending a lot of money.
>
> **Visual Studio Professional**
>
> Visual Studio Professional is a Microsoft Collaborative Development
> Area. It is used to build software, blogs, desktop browsers, online
> services, and smartphone applications.
>
> **Visual Studio Enterprise**
>
> Visual Studio Enterprise contains a Mac Digital design. You can
> recognize and enjoy the same visual studio interface, which has been
> beautifully built and optimized for Mac. It is counted as the most
> dynamic and is filled with rich and new features. Software architects
> can use this medium in the best possible way and make the most out of
> it effortlessly.
>
> Develop new, quicker, and simpler than ever before, windows, or
> Mac-based mobile applications with enterprise-grade software. It has
> been specifically designed to help you experience the best services
> and state-of-the-art features.
>
> **Visual Studio Community vs. Professional**
>
> The Visual Studio Community is open, whereas the professional edition
> is not accessible. The community can be used by developers or a
> smaller team of at least five individuals. But there are few
> limitations to the professional edition.
>
> It can also be used by a group of 5 to 25 developers. Another
> important distinction is that the professional version supports the
> business, while the visual studio community does not. The predominant
> distinction between community edition and professional edition is a
> widely renowned feature known as CodeLens. There are a plethora of
> significant benefits that are offered by CodeLens, such as the users
> can easily determine code changes along with other pertinent
> histories.
>
> One more important point that has to be addressed here is that the
> difference between them shrinks considerably. However, when you are
> supposed to be working in a large team, only then is the difference
> relevant. These could be automated unit tests or collaboration tools.
> Individual developers or even small teams incorporate the community
> edition for the purpose of commercial development. Now, this small
> group might involve five.
>
> **Visual Studio Community vs. Enterprise**
>
> Visual Studio Enterprise is for major corporations that get more
> sales and earnings per year. At the same time, the community edition
> is a free version, which can either be used for open source projects,
> for research purposes or as a team of five or fewer developers, under
> a variety of conditions.
>
> **Visual Studio Professional vs. Enterprise**
>
> The Enterprise version is filled with many features compared to the
> Visual Studio Professional edition.

Check this [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) to compare the differences between the different versions

**Hence, if you like to use Visual Studio Version for your own benefit, the community edition suits the best; there is no advantage of using Enterprise rather than Community Edition. Always remember, community edition is the professional edition for personal applications.**

You can also debug in VS code, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

[image]

Check the [**MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/)

[image]

Comment: I knew there are differences between Community & other versions. But it is not my concern. I just want to know if I could develop .NET MVC/core application and sell this app/web commercially. whatever any team size I am (like node.js).

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, I have edited my answer and add `MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS`'s link. 
If you want to use Microsoft products in the enterprise, you should read it carefully.

Comment: oh, so it means that actually VS community is also not free for company. And they already assumed if VS is applied in an company, they should subscribe. Am I correct?